# numpy random not working with seed

Tags: python, numpy

```
import random
seed = random.random()
random_seed  = random.Random(seed)
random_vec = [ random_seed.random() for i in range(10)]
```

The above is essentially:

```
np.random.randn(10)
```

But I am not able to figure out how to set the seed?

Comment: Why do you _want_ to set the seed? Especially to a random number?

Comment: Setting seeds is important for reproducibility in some analyses

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why you *want* to set the seed—especially to a random number, even more especially to a random float (note that [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) wants a large integer).

But if you do, it's simple: call the [`numpy.random.seed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html#numpy.random.seed) function.

Note that NumPy's seeds are arrays of 32-bit integers, while Python's seeds are single arbitrary-sized integers (although see the docs for what happens when you pass other types).

So, for example:

```
In [1]: np.random.seed(0)    
In [2]: s = np.random.randn(10)
In [3]: s
Out[3]:
array([ 1.76405235,  0.40015721,  0.97873798,  2.2408932 ,  1.86755799,
       -0.97727788,  0.95008842, -0.15135721, -0.10321885,  0.4105985 ])
In [4]: np.random.seed(0)
In [5]: s = np.random.randn(10)
In [6]: s
Out[6]:
array([ 1.76405235,  0.40015721,  0.97873798,  2.2408932 ,  1.86755799,
       -0.97727788,  0.95008842, -0.15135721, -0.10321885,  0.4105985 ])
```

Same seed used twice (I took the shortcut of passing a single `int`, which NumPy will internally convert into an array of 1 `int32`), same random numbers generated.

Comment: You are assigning to `s` just once here, hence `s` will always be the same independently of setting seed a second time.

Comment: you forgot to assign a second time `s = np.random.randn(10)`, however, the end result shall be the same.

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply `random.seed(value)` does not work with numpy arrays.
For example,

```
import random
import numpy as np
random.seed(10)
print( np.random.randint(1,10,10)) #generates 10 random integer of values from 1~10

[4 1 5 7 9 2 9 5 2 4]

random.seed(10)
print( np.random.randint(1,10,10))

[7 6 4 7 2 5 3 7 8 9]
```

However, if you want to seed the numpy generated values, you have to use `np.random.seed(value)`.
If I revisit the above example,

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
print( np.random.randint(1,10,10))

[5 1 2 1 2 9 1 9 7 5]

np.random.seed(10)
print( np.random.randint(1,10,10))

[5 1 2 1 2 9 1 9 7 5]
```